# The set {x ∈ $R^n$: $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$}

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I don't really understand the notation of this set: {x ∈ $R^n$: $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$}
what would be exemplary numerical values for this set?
Would it be e.g. [0.3 ; 0.7] or e.g. [0.1 ; 0.2 ; 0.3 ; 0.4]?

Comment: It depends on the value of $n$. If $n = 2$, then you are in the plane and your set contains all the pairs $(x, 1-x)$, hence $(0.3, 0.7)$. But if $n=4$, then your set contains (amongst infinitely many other) $(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4)$

Comment: Basically it is the set of all points of  $R^n$ whose coordinates add up to $1$

Comment: Maybe this is of interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex

Comment: Is it the $\sum$ notation that you do not understand? Or is it $\mathbf{x}\in\Bbb R^n$? There are two answers posted now that explain the latter part, but if it is the former that you have problems with, you may consult https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation and https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-integration-new/ab-6-3/a/review-summation-notation But, you are right,  [0.3 ; 0.7] is an exemplary numerical value when $n=2$, and [0.1 ; 0.2 ; 0.3 ; 0.4]  exemplary numerical value when $n=4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

First $\Bbb R^n$ is the set of all $n$-dimensional vectors. Using components, an $n$-dimensional vector 
$\mathbf{x}$ is an odrered $n$=tuple $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$. 
Or, perhaps it is better to think of this $n$-tuple as the coordinates of a point, as follows: $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ is a point in $n$-dimensional space.

As pointed out in the comments, if $n=2$ then we are talking about pairs $(x_1,x_2)$. Think of this as a point with coordinates $(x_1,x_2)$, that is a point $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2)$. Then the set 
$\{\mathbf{x}\in\Bbb R^2:\sum_{i=1}^2x_i=1\}$ is the same as the set 
$\{(x_1,x_2):\sum_{i=1}^2x_i=1\}$, that is 
$\{(x_1,x_2):x_1+x_2=1\}$. Usually when $n=2$ one denotes coordinates $(x_1,x_2)$ as $(x,y)$, so 
we could write our set as $\{(x,y):x+y=1\}$. 
This set is the same as the set of all points on the straight line (in the plane) represented by equation 
$x+y=1$, or, what is the same, $y=-x+1$, a line with slope $-1$ and $y$-intersept $1$ (as shown below).

[image: line x+y=1]

When $n=3$ then we are talking about triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, that is $\mathbf{x}\in\Bbb R^3$ and $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. Think of this as a point in (three-dimensional) space with coordinates $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. Then the set 
$\{\mathbf{x}\in\Bbb R^3:\sum_{i=1}^3x_i=1\}$ is the same as the set 
$\{(x_1,x_2,x_3):\sum_{i=1}^3x_i=1\}$, that is 
$\{(x_1,x_2,x_3):x_1+x_2+x_3=1\}$. Usually when $n=3$ one denotes coordinates $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ as $(x,y,z)$, so 
we could write our set as $\{(x,y,z):x+y+z=1\}$. 
This set is the same as the set of all points on the plane (in 3D space) represented by equation 
$x+y+z=1$. (Could also be written as $z=1-x-y$.) It is easy to compute the intercepts of this plane with the coordinate axes. Indeed, when $y=z=0$ we get $x=1$, the $x$-intercept. Similarly 
when $x=z=0$ we get $y=1$, the $y$-intercept.
When $x=y=0$ we get $z=1$, the $z$-intercept. 
Here is a plot of this plane (in three dimensional space).

[image: plane x plus y plus z equals 1]

Answer (score 1):

Given a point x in N dimensional space x$_i$ the i-th coordinate.
For example if the point p = (a,b,c), then p$_2$ = b.

The set itself is a hyperplane passing through the unit of each coordinate.
For n = 2 it is { (x,y) : x + y = 1 }, the line passing (1,0) and (0,1).
For n = 3 it is { (x,y,z) : x + y + z = 1 }, the plane passing through (1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,0,1).

Your examples are correct, your notation isn't.

Comment: Sorry I posted more or less the same answer as yours, I had written it when I spent a couple of hours looking for an online plotter to plot the plane $x+y+z=1$ didn't like what was available and ended up making a plot "by hand" using paint (Windows), and finally posted it.